# How to receive timer events in CWinApp with MFC?

Tags: winapi, mfc

In MFC I'm trying to set a null handler timer (ie. no windows). But I'm unable to process the WM_TIMER event in the CWinApp MESSAGE_MAP. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As told by MSDN, there are two modes of operation for [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906.aspx): one that associates a timer with a window, and one that associates a timer with a thread's message queue. When you have a window, you can use the former; otherwise, you must use the latter. And `CWinApp` *isn't* a window.

#### Catching timer messages in the thread queue

```
UINT_PTR uTimerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 2000, NULL);
TRACE(_T("Timer created - ID=%x\n"), uTimerId);
```

This will create a new timer, set to fire every two seconds, associated only with the current thread's message queue. You don't get to specify a timer ID when you aren't associating it with a window, so save the ID returned in a class member or something - [you'll have a rough time killing the timer later on if you forget](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/16/9001218.aspx). You could then process this in a `CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage()` override:

```
BOOL CMyFunkyApp::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
   if (pMsg->message == WM_TIMER)
   {
      TRACE(_T("Timer fired - ID=%x\n"), pMsg->wParam);
   }

   return CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Note that hooking into the thread's message loop like this is the *only* way to handle a timer set up this way - as we discussed, there's no window, and although MFC does provide a message map facility for `CWinApp` you can't use the `ON_WM_*()` macros because... well, because *it's not a window*. However, there is another, *slightly* less-messy way: callbacks.

#### Handling timer messages with a callback

```
void CALLBACK TimerCallback(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR id, DWORD dwTime)
{
   TRACE(_T("Timer fired - ID=%x\n"), id);
}

//...

UINT_PTR uTimerId = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 2000, &TimerCallback);
TRACE(_T("Timer created - ID=%x\n"), uTimerId);
```

This does almost *exactly* the same thing as the first example: a new timer is configured to fire every two seconds, associated with the current thread's message queue... but *this* one has a callback address associated with it. And the default message handler knows to call the callback when such a timer message is processed, so you don't have to bother hooking into the message loop.

So there you go. Two ways of using timers from `CWinApp`.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by making an invisible window and setting a timer on it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this post by Raymond Chen.  There are some interesting nuggets for what your working on that might keep you out of trouble.

[Why your thread is spending all its time processing meaningless thread timers](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/16/9001218.aspx)